# net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) on webcomponent

Tags: angular, server, http-status-code-404, web-component

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWnsJ.png). I have made a angular web component and I wanted to test it. so i created an index.html file and kept it in a folder. when i try to run it using live server on vs code it works fine, but when I try to run it using npx http-server  or in another angular projects it throws 404. I checked the path to the script and it is correct. what could be the reason?

Comment: Check F12 Network tab to see which assets are not found (404)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error by adding the scripts in angular.json file